# ¿Como saco en una única ventana emergente los múltiplos del numero 5 al pulsar un botón?

Tags: javascript

Si hay una manera más fácil de simplificarlo, por favor decírmelo así me ayudaría mucho, he estado haciendo esto durante más de 3 horas, y no puedo saber como arreglarlo, el output es solamente todos los múltiplos sumados dando 30 si pones 25, este es mi código:

```js
function multiple5() {
  var num1, num2, num3 = 5, num4 = "", mult = 5, result;

  num1 = parseInt(prompt("Introduce un número:", ""));

  if (num1 >> 0) {
    num2 = num1;
    num1 = 1;
    for (num1 = num1; num2 >= num1; num1++) {
      result = num1 % mult;
      if (result == 0) {
        num3 = num3 + mult;
        num4 = num3;
        //text();
      }
    }
    alert(num4 + " ");
  } else {
    alert("Lo siento pero el número introducido no es mayor a 0");
  }
}
```

```html
<form name="formulario" method="post" action="">
  <input type="button" onClick="multiple5()" value="Multiples de 5">
</form>
```

Comment: Tal vez deberías explicar qué quieres conseguir exactamente, porque analizando el código no consigo averiguar cual es su cometido exacto.

Comment: Bueno y el error cual sería?...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Por lo que entiendo viendo tu codigo y la explicación, por cada múltiplo que haya en el número, sumas 5 al total. Se podrías simplificar un poco así:

```html
<html>
    <title>JavaScript</title>
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/hmtl"; charset="UTF-8">
    <script language="JavaScript">
    function multiple5(){
    const multiple = 5;
    let total = multiple;
    num1 = parseInt(prompt("Introduce un número:",""));
    
    if(num1>0){
        for (let num = multiple ;num <= num1;num = num + multiple){
            if(num % multiple === 0) total = total + multiple;
            //si lo que quieres es sumar los multiplos, sería esta linea que 
            //sigue e inicializar la variable total a 0
            //if(num % multiple === 0) total = total + num;
        }
        alert(total +" ");
    }else{
        alert("Lo siento pero el número introducido no es mayor a 0");
    }
    
}

    </script>
    
    <form name="formulario" method="post" action="">
        <input type="button" onClick="multiple5()" value="Multiples de 5">
    </form>
</html>
```

Comment: Ojo con la expresión `if(num1>>0)` lo que significa es "si num1 es distinto a 0",  lo digo porque en el else el mensaje que sale es que el número no es mayor a 0. No sé si es un error y quería hacer una comparación "mayor que", pero tal y como está si le pasas un número negativo lo cogería tranquilamente.

Comment: Correcto, editado